# List and Maximum Numbers without using built in functions

Tags: python

I need some help with my assignment:

> Using a for loop, write a function called getMax4 that takes in a list of numbers. It determines and returns the maximum number that is divisible by 4.
>   The function returns -999 if the argument is an empty list
>   The function returns 0 if no number in the argument list is divisible by 4.

The following shows sample outputs when the function is called:

[image]

I've managed to do the following in my code:

```
def getMax4(list):
    highest = 0
    if len(list) == 0:
        return -999
    else:
        for number in list:
            if number % 4 == 0:
                if number < highest:
                    highest = number

                else:
                    highest = 0               
                return number
print(getMax4([]))
print(getMax4([1, 3, 9]))
print(getMax4([-4, 3, -12, -8, 13]))
print(getMax4([1, 16, 18, 12]))
```

The Output for me was as follows:

[image]

I don't understand why the value was determined as `None`, when it should be `0`.

Comment: Note that your code is the (rather ugly) one-liner:  `lambda lst: next((x for x in lst if x%4==0), 0) if len(lst) > 0 else -999`. That will even pass all your test cases. It is not, however, correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's walk through execution of your code.

```
def getMax4(list):
    highest = 0
    if len(list) == 0:
        return -999
    else:
        for number in list:
            if number % 4 == 0:
                if number < highest:
                    highest = number

                else:
                    highest = 0               
                return number
```

The obvious case is a length zero list, and it handles them correctly. Woohoo.

The other obvious case is a list with numbers divisible by four. Let's look at that:

```
# imagine getMax4([[1, 16, 20, 12])
# note that this is different from your example, because your example doesn't
# highlight a meaningful bug!

# unroll the for loop:

number = 1
if number % 4 == 0:  # it doesn't, so skip
number = 16
if number % 4 == 0:
    if number < highest:  # it's not, but this should pass. Your comparison is backwards here!
    else:
        highest = 0  # what?? we reset it?? Why??!
    return number
```

So we've identified a couple issues already, including the fact that as soon as we find a number that's divisible by four -- we return that number as the solution, even though the correct answer here was 20. That's obviously wrong!

Let's step in and fix those.

```
def getMax4(list):
    highest = 0
    if len(list) == 0:
        return -999
    else:
        for number in list:
            if number % 4 == 0:
                if number > highest:  # flip comparison
                    highest = number
                # removed the else clause
        return highest  # pulled this all the way out past the for loop's end
```

Now let's walk through the same call with the new code

```
# getMax4([[1, 16, 20, 12])

# unroll the for loop
number = 1
if 1 % 4 == 0:  # it's not
number = 16
if 16 % 4 == 0:  # it is!
    if 16 > 0:  # it is!
        highest = 16  # remember it
number = 20
if 20 % 4 == 0:  # bingo!
    if 20 > 16:  # yup-a-roonie
        highest = 20  # remember this one now. We can forget 16
number = 12
if 12 % 4 == 0:  # batting 1.000
    if 12 > 20:  # not this time, buck-o.

# now we're all done with the for loop, so we step outside and find
return number  # which is 20
```

---

Now we can look at cleaning this up a bit:

```
def getMax4(list):
    highest = 0
    if len(list) == 0:
        return -999
    # whenever you have an early-exit conditional, there's no reason to
    # write the rest in an `else`. Just omit the `else` and dedent.
    for number in list:
        if number % 4 == 0:
            if number > highest:
                highest = number
    return highest
```

Comment: I recommend you avoid using the word `list`, it is a reserved word that could cause problems difficult to debug, consider it a bad practice.

Comment: Wow, Thank you for the in-depth explanation!

Comment: `assert getMax4([-4, 3, -12, -8, 13]) == -4` ?

Comment: @eyllanesc agreed, but that didn't factor in here and there's already enough to critique that I think it only muddies the waters to include it in the answer.

Comment: @G_M ah shoot, yeah. I guess you should probably have `highest` unset (`highest = None`) to start and check if it's `None` in each `if number % 4 == 0` before `if number > highest`. Then you can `return highest or 0`. (I mean, really you should probably abandon this algorithm completely and use something a little more batteries-included, but you know what I mean :D)

Comment: @AdamSmith 
it is not necessary to criticize or explain but only to avoid using list ;)

Comment: @eyllanesc ehh I'm not going to change the user's code when that part isn't faulting. I agree it's bad practice and it will probably bite him in the ass someday, but it's not doing that here and there's no shortage of things to correct, so that's just too far down on my list of priorities. It detracts from the answer.

Comment: @AdamSmith 
The last thing I will say is that the answer should not only serve the asker but the community, and many take as a basis the answers of users with high reputation, if you take my advice or not your decision, goodbye :)

Answer (score 1):

One more thing to remind, donot use build in name as variable, such as `list`,`str`,`int`,`float`,`tuple`,`type`, it will give you nasty result if you call these build in as function later. Therefore I suggest you change list to numbers.

Because it only `return number` if it goes in your if statement:

```
if number % 4 == 0:
```

To return 0:

Simply ident `return number` to your for loop.

Like,

```
def getMax4(numbers):
    highest = []
    if len(numbers) == 0:
        return -999
    else:
        for number in numbers:
            if number % 4 == 0:
                if highest==[] or number > highest:
                    highest = number             
        return highest if highest!=[] else 0
```

Comment: @OP Though it looks cleanest if you remove the `else` statement since it is unnecessary indenting and might contribute to the confusion.

Comment: Though I would add to change your parameter name from list to `numbers` since the variable name `list` shadows the builtin function `list`

Comment: `assert getMax4([16, 4]) == 16`?

Comment: @G_M 2, sorry, changed,haha

Comment: `assert getMax4([-4, 3, -12, -8, 13]) == -4`?

Comment: @G_M , you are absolutely right. Updated, haha, I blindly trust the OP's logic. It is my bad.

Answer (score -3):

Just a minor change to the existing code, return 0 to be added explicitly.

```
def getMax4(list):
    highest = 0
    if len(list) == 0:
        return -999
    else:
        for number in list:
            if number % 4 == 0:
                if number < highest:
                    highest = number

                else:
                    highest = 0               
                return number

    return 0
```

Comment: Not sure why this was accepted as it is wrong. If the `number < highest` condition is false, we can premature end our traversal of the list of numbers. Consider the case `[-1, 4]`. This returns `0` when the real answer is `4`.

Comment: @Skam Running the code with `print(getMax4([-1, 4]))` returns 4 and not 0

Comment: @madmatrix that works for a single case does not imply that it is correct.

Comment: So I should change the sign to > ?